# Create a Shared Access Signature (SAS) for an Azure Cloud Storage Account with powershell

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell

How do I create a SAS url for my entire cloud storage account?

I noticed the azure powershell cmdlets have a lot of ways to create SAS urls for specific resources (e.g. blob, queue, etc..), but I would like to create one SAS for all of them with powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to use Azure storage [account SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#types-of-shared-access-signatures). More details please refer to the [New-AzureStorageAccountSASToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestorageaccountsastoken?view=azuresmps-4.0.0)

```
New-AzureStorageAccountSASToken
   -Service <SharedAccessAccountServices>
   -ResourceType <SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes>
   [-Permission <String>]
   [-Protocol <SharedAccessProtocol>]
   [-IPAddressOrRange <String>]
   [-StartTime <DateTime>]
   [-ExpiryTime <DateTime>]
   [-Context <IStorageContext>]
   [<CommonParameters>]



example : New-AzureStorageAccountSASToken -Service Blob,File,Table,Queue -ResourceType Service,Container,Object -Permission "racwdlup" -Context $ctx
```

**Edit:**

> I have already tried this API. It does not allow you to specify which Azure StorageAccount to generate the SAS for.

I test with resource mangment storage account, it works correctly on my side. Details please refer to the screenshot.

```
$resourceGroup = "Resource group"
$storageAccountName = "account name "

Login-AzureRmAccount

$storageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storageAccountName 

$ctx = $storageAccount.Context

$accountSAS = New-AzureStorageAccountSASToken -Service Blob,File,Table,Queue -ResourceType Service,Container,Object -Permission "racwdlup" -Context $ctx
```

[image]

Comment: No unfortunately that API does not work as expected. There is a older version of azure storage accounts and the API you mention is used to create SAS tokens for it. I need to be able to create SAS tokens for the current version of Azure Storage

Comment: Please have a try to use the Powershell command `New-AzureStorageAccountSASToken -Service Blob,File,Table,Queue -ResourceType Service,Container,Object -Permission "racwdlup"`.  This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#types-of-shared-access-signatures) is related to account sas and service sas.

Comment: I have already tried this API. It does not allow you to specify which Azure StorageAccount to generate the SAS for. Calling the matching `Set-AzureStorageAccount` only works with old Storage accounts and not with new ones.

Comment: Sorry,  What does `I have already tried this API`  means? I have updated the answer and test it with resource management  storage account

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me :) I was missing the -Context parameter. Which, when omitted, defaults to whatever was previously set via `Set-AzureStorageAccount` (I believe). As far as I can tell `Set-AzureStorageAccount` only works with RM resources, so when I tried it, it wasn't working.